# struct accessible without declaration?

Tags: c, struct, compiler-flags

I have the following Code

```
#ifdef ENV_TI
typedef struct timespecT
{
    Uint32 tv_sec;
    Uint32 tv_nsec; 
}timespec;
#endif
#ifndef ENV_TI
struct timespec currentTime; // This Line
#else 
timespec currentTime;
#endif
```

How is the `currentTime` accessible if i have NOT defined `ENV_TI` flag and the timespec is defined under the `ENV_TI` flag?

I am running this code on *Linux*, *gcc* compiler.

Comment: Are you sure you are not missing an `#endif` somewhere? There is a mismatch in this code snippet.

Comment: Yes am sorry about that, will make the change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`struct timespec` is a type name used in e.g. Linux, see [the manual page for `clock_gettime()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/clock_gettime). You get the type declaration by doing `#include <time.h>` on systems that support it. According to the manual page, this is POSIX standard functionality.

I think the code you're looking at is using the `#ifdef` to declare the type for environments that don't support it natively.

Answer (score 0):

timespec is also the name of a struct defined in *time.h*